# Hash and salt or salt and hash?

Tags: hash, salt, terminology

People say "hash and salt", but aren't you supposed to salt password the first, and then hash it?

So that means its called "salt and hash" right?

Comment: Actually, with the big three proper password hashes the salt is just another input into the algorithm, rather than "salting the password" being an operation in its own right (the operations are "generate salt" and "compute hash with these parameters, this password, and this salt").

Comment: You should not be writing code to hash passwords yourself. Use [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) and you won't have to care about details like these. Bindings are available for virtually any language you wish.

Comment: @cpast Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you're right.